# Symmetric group S9

Tags: abstract-algebra

Does the symmetric group S9 have an element of order 12?

Having some trouble figuring out this problem, any help/hints would be great.

Comment: Tell me what is the order of $(123)$ and $(4567)$ is $S_9$ ?

Comment: @ChinnapparajR 3 and 4?

Comment: Fine! so  what is the order of $(123)(4567)$ ?

Comment: 12, but is this still in S9?

Comment: Why not? $(123)(4567)$ means $(123)(4567)(8)(9)$

Comment: @ChinnapparajR AH Yes! Sorry i was being silly. Thank you:)

Comment: make your observations to write your own answer  and accepting it to finish this question

Comment: @ChinnapparajR just as a food for thought, would the alternating group of $A_9$ have an element of order 6? and would this just be a 2-cycle and 3-cycle?

Comment: No! a product of 2 cycle and a 3 cycle is odd. Instead , take $(123)(45)(67)(8)(9)$

Comment: @ChinnapparajR is that of order 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the product of disjoint cycles: (123)(4567) has an order of 12, and therefore is in $S_9$

Answer (score 1):

To get an element of order 12, it should have parts that are of order 3 and four or something like that, so $(2,3,4,1)(6,7,5)(8)(9)$ should be of order 12

Comment: How $(234167589)$ is of order $12$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I think we are using different notation. What I meant was 1→2, 2→3, 3→4, 4→1, 5→6, 6→7, 7→5, 8→8, 9→9. This is essentially the same thing as @Reety was saying

Comment: Wrong way around, this is what @Chinnaparaj R was saying, sorry

Comment: But generally $(....16...)$ means $1 \mapsto 6$ so change your notation!

Comment: Okay, I have fixed it now. I was trying to write something similar to \begin{matrix}
  $  1 & 2 & 3 \\
      2 & 3 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}$, since I have seen that notation before, but I can see how that wasn't very clear

Answer (score 0):

$|(1234)(567)(8)(9)|=|(1234)(567)|=12$ and $(1234)(567)$ in $S_9$